# Python: exception in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc

Im trying to execute a program in a python subprocess:

```
class MiThread(threading.Thread):  
      def __init__(self):  
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)   

      def run(self):
        try:
            from Queue import Queue, Empty
        except ImportError:
    #from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x
            print "error"
        ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()
        p= Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/',stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize= 4024)
        q = Queue()
        t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        print "estoy en el hilo"
        t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        t.start()

                print l
```

But when i execute the thread it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GNS3/Workspace.py", line 65, in run
    t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
NameError: global name 'Thread' is not defined

QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

i dont have any idea! What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
```

to:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
```

In your current namespace, `Thread` exists as `threading.Thread` (a member of the `threading` module), so when you say `Thread` alone, Python can't find a match and throws that error.

Comment: Thank you @RocketDonkey i fixed Thread's error! But the following error is occuring yet:`QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)` Any idea?

Comment: @karensantana Glad to hear it - as for the second error, that looks like a QT-related issue, and unfortunately I know literally nothing about it :) However I did a quick search, and it appears that you need to both create and register meta types, and from the code examples I saw, it is not done in Python (this is only based on ~5  minutes of research though - I could be missing something). Not sure if this (http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.1/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) makes sense to you, but that seems to be related to the error.

Comment: @karensantana Also, if that doesn't work, you could try asking a new question - there are loads of smart people around here and somebody is bound to be a Qt expert :) Good luck with everything!